# Qt can't inherit properties

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance

I'm having troubles with properties.

So I have some Classes (UML)

```
CNode
   |--CNode2D
         |--CSprite2D
```

`CNode` has these following Properties:

```
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ getName WRITE setName)
Q_PROPERTY(bool visible READ getVisible WRITE setVisible)
Q_PROPERTY(bool enabled READ getEnabled WRITE setEnabled)
```

`CNode2D` has those:

```
Q_OBJECT
Q_PROPERTY(float Position_X READ getPosX WRITE setPosX)
Q_PROPERTY(float Position_Y READ getPosY WRITE setPosY)
Q_PROPERTY(float height READ getHeight WRITE setHeight)
```

`CSprite2D` has none...

If I try to print out the Properties in the constructor of `CSprite2D`

```
for(int i = metaObject()->propertyOffset(); i < metaObject()->propertyCount(); ++i)
{
      qDebug() << metaObject()->property(i).name() << metaObject()->property(i).read(this);
}
```

I only get outputted the properties of `CNode2D`

```
Position_X QVariant(float, 7.47779e+21)
Position_Y QVariant(float, 4.58827e-41)
height QVariant(float, 0)
```

Which leads me to think that `CNode2D` doesn't inherit of the properties of `CNode`...

Only `CNode` inherits from `QObject`.

If I make inherit the other two Classes from `QObject`, I get thrown compilation errors at me.

I'm new to Qt, so I might have forgotten something important, in this case, sorry.

EDIT: HERE ARE THE CLASS DEFINITIONS (I removed the includes):

```
    class CNode: public QObject
{
public:
    CNode();
    QString getName();
    void setName(QString nameI);
    bool getVisible ();
    void setVisible (bool i);
    void setEnabled(bool i);
    bool getEnabled();

public slots:
    void nameChanged();
    void visibleChanged();
    void enabledChanged();

public: //properties

    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ getName WRITE setName)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool visible READ getVisible WRITE setVisible)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool enabled READ getEnabled WRITE setEnabled)

protected:
    QTreeWidgetItem* nodeListItem;
    QString name;
    bool enabled;
    bool visible; //if the node has to get rendered
};



    class CNode2D: public CNode
{
public:
    CNode2D();
    virtual ~CNode2D();
    void setPosX(float i);
    float getPosX();
    float getPosY();
    void  setPosY(float i);
    float getHeight();
    void  setHeight(float i);

public slots:
    void posXChanged();
    void posYChanged();
    void heightChanged();

public:
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(float Position_X READ getPosX WRITE setPosX)
    Q_PROPERTY(float Position_Y READ getPosY WRITE setPosY)
    Q_PROPERTY(float height READ getHeight WRITE setHeight)

protected:
    float height;
    float posX;
    float posY;
};


class CSprite2D: public CNode2D
{
public:
    CSprite2D(int number, Ui::MainWindow *i);
    ~CSprite2D();
    int getPosX();
    int getPosY();
    void compile();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    int number_sprite;
    QString spriteLink;
    void drawSprite();
};
```

Comment: can you show your classes definition? CNode should inherit QObject, QNode2D should inherit QNode and QSprite2D should inherit CNode2D. Are you using multiple inheritance? The docs say: "The READ, WRITE, and RESET functions can be inherited. They can also be virtual. When they are inherited in classes where multiple inheritance is used, they must come from the first inherited class." So maybe you have another class inherited before yours?

Comment: @transistor I edited the question

Comment: on the first view, it looks ok to me. With Qt, it can never hurt to run qmake again, if something isn't working as expected. Seems that the internal structure sometimes need a refresh. I regularly hit qmake/rebuild all if I added/removed QObjects. Also, you should add the "Q_OBJECT" macro to your classes (missing, in CSprite2D, also the Destructor should be virtual).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tried some code, as I was curious:

You have to add another loop for accessing also the superclass' properties like so:

```
for(int i = metaObject()->superClass()->propertyOffset(); i < metaObject()->superClass()->propertyCount(); ++i)
{
      qDebug() << metaObject()->superClass()->property(i).name() << metaObject()->superClass()->property(i).read(this);
}
```

Just calling metaObject() accesses only the derived instance and not the parents.

Comment: Thanks... Is there a way to make this easyer? because it pisses me that I always have to add that second loop... Couldn't I just add a vector of pointers to properties?

Comment: sorry, I don't use the Qt Property System in our products, so I don't know it too deply. What special use case do you have, that you really need it?

Comment: I'm building a game-engine... Every node has some properties (name, positionX, positionY) and so on...